# How to start and shutdown jmeter slaves from the master

Tags: jmeter, master-slave

In my test environment i want to start the jmeter slaves from master before the test and shutdown the slaves after the test. How to do these from jmeter master? The test environment is in CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your command line :

> -X

Example:

> jmeter -n -t testplan.jmx -r -X

`-X` means to exit the servers at the end of the test.

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using one of the following approaches:

1. [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) in combination with [ssh command](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssh1.html) (or [plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/plink.exe) if master is on Windows)
2. [SSH Sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler) (available via plugin)

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) guide for details.